# C# with azure storage getting exception when using DeleteIfExists()

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I get an exception when using the method `DeleteIfExists` from the `CloudBlockBlob`  class.

This is my code:

```
CloudBlobClient blobClient = this._storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            directory = directory.ToLower();

            string containerDirectory = this.GetContainer(directory);
            string relativePathWithoutContainer = this.GetRelativePathWithoutContainer(directory);

            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerDirectory);
            container.CreateIfNotExist();
            container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions() { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });

            foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
            {
                CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(string.Format("{0}/{1}", relativePathWithoutContainer, file.FileName.ToLower()));
                blob.DeleteIfExists();
                blob.UploadFromStream(file.InputStream,new BlobRequestOptions());
            }

            return true;
```

I get the exception at the line:

```
blob.DeleteIfExists();
```

The details of the exception are:

> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of
>   Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got an example from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee772904.aspx) try to add these and see if it works

// Delete the blob if it already exists, also deleting any snapshots.

```
BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions();

options.DeleteSnapshotsOption = DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots;

blob.DeleteIfExists(options);
```